# Two group clustering in residuals - not sure how to fix

Tags: regression, residuals, treatment-effect

My only really significant finding in this study has strange residuals - two clusters. It's a study of the treatment effect of education on psychological capital pre vs. post-test, so I'm assuming the errors are clustered around the pre and post-test? I'm also controlling for age, gender, and work experience, so gender could be the problem? Not sure what to do with this. Any help is much appreciated!

[image: residual plots]

Comment: The residuals do not seem to form two clusters, but the fitted values do.

Comment: Perhaps try to study the relation between sex and the dependent variable and then between sex and the fitted values.

Comment: @Ertxiem - my regression output is below: 
Test_Period2  9.457*** (2.214)
 
Age                 -0.529    (0.503)
 
Sex                -1.083     (2.424)
 
Work_Exp 0.423     (0.522)
 
Constant 106.026***    (12.496)
------------------------
Observations 113
R2 0.153
Adjusted R2 0.122
Residual St. Er 11.765
F-stat 4.885***

It looks like being female has a negative effect on psychological capital (sadly). Do you think this may be the reason?

Comment: Can you please edit your post and include this last information in there, it will be easier to read.    Regarding what you shown, I would guess that Test_Period2 might be the reason. Is it a $0$ or $1$ variable? An alternative would be age, if there are two clusters in the dataset. Sex does not seem to be the issue because it's coefficient is $-1$ and the clusters differ by $10$ units.